# Need regular expression to match android 4.2.1 and above

Tags: java, android, regex, expression

In a project I need to find if the user is using android 4.2.1 and above. Please help

I have android verion as a String in java. I am aware i cam do this without using regular expression, but i just need to try it using regular expression

I can use something like

```
Version = "4.2.2"
if(version.matches("[4-99]\\.[2-99]\\.[0-99]")) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false
}
```

This works till android 5.0.0 is released and after that it fails till 5.2.0

Comment: Why not just use `int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
`?

Comment: Why 4.2.1? It doesn't introduce any new features compared to 4.2.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `RELEASE` version that has 2 or 3 levels: major, minor and build respectively:

```
String myVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE;

    String osMajor = "0";
    String osMinor = "0";
    String osBuild = "0";

    if(myVersion.matches("[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+")){
        osMajor = myVersion.split("\\.")[0];
        osMinor = myVersion.split("\\.")[1];
        osBuild = myVersion.split("\\.")[2];
    }
    else if(myVersion.matches("[0-9]+.[0-9]+")){
        osMajor = myVersion.split("\\.")[0];
        osMinor = myVersion.split("\\.")[1];

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure if it can be done in a single expression like version.matches("[4-99].[0-99][0-99]").. the above will return true if version is 4.0.0 and above. My problem occures when i need to know 4.2.1 and above

Comment: after this logic ask if `osMajor >=4; osMinor >=2;`

Comment: make your code simple and clear. In some test case the regex can fail so with above way will be easy to debug and leave the logs.

Comment: Thanks Maxim for the code and advice. I would like to know if it can be solved using regex though

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html

`android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE` returns the user-visible version string. E.g., "1.0" or "3.4b5".

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
String[] duh = version.split(".");

// Convert the three version numbers to 3 ints, and then....

int vers = (int1 * 100) + (int2 * 10) + int3;
```

Comment: Thank you. Yet I am looking for a regular expression way to solve this

Comment: You can't.  RE's are just for editing a string, not doing compound if statements.